# Python 3 Tkinter closing frame after command

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Goodevening everybody,
In tkinter python3, suppose i have a frame with two button each of them executing a program. Just fter either one of the two being executed, id like  to close the frame to open another one with other widget. While I have no problems coding a second frame2=Frame(root,etc), Im unsure about the transition.

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: Sorry, i meant " suppose i have a frame with two button each of them executing a COMMAND"

Comment: "unsure about the transition" is a bit too vague. The method for deleting a widget is documented and there are many examples on the internet. What have you tried? Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?